# Search box with select option of custom search

Tags: html, css, google-custom-search, search-box

How to create search box with select option of google custom search engine in one field.
I have the code but I don't know how to combine between the different types of my custom search engines to select option in the dropdown:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /></head><body style="background-color:transparent; margin:3px; padding:0px;">
<form action="https://www.google.com/cse" id="cse1" target="_top" onsubmit='this["q"].value = this["sitesearch"].value + document.getElementById("searchQuery").value'>
<input type="hidden" name="q" value="" />
<input id="searchQuery" type="text" style="width:440px;" maxlength="255" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="sitesearch" value="" /><input type="hidden" name="cx" value="00000000000000000000000:aaaaaaaaaaa" />
<span id="search-page-border">
<label class="accessibly-hidden"></label>
<label for="search-which" class="accessibly-hidden"></label><select name="" id="" style="width: auto"><option value="cse1">Google Custom Search 1</option><option value="cse2">Google Custom Search 2</option></select> </span>
<input type="submit" name="" id="" value="search" />
</form>
```

Thank you very much

Comment: i have a website with forums and blogs, i created two custom search engines, one for blog and other for forum and i want to create search box with select option of the two diffrent types of my google custom search, thank you

Comment: yes, i want my visitors will be able to choose the type of search in the drop-down, thanks

Comment: you can copy the code i added and paste it to this website http://htmledit.squarefree.com/

Comment: I recommend [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4J2g6/) instead

Answer (score 0):

I have an example of such solution here: http://edu.schema-labs.appspot.com/ .You can choose the engine from the dropdown ("whole web", "curated index") and it's cx gets appended to the url. Then I grab the cx from urlparam and render the engine programatically:

```
var init = function(cx) {
  var gcse = document.createElement('script'); gcse.type = 'text/javascript'; gcse.async = true;
  gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
      '//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
};

function getURLParameter(name) {
    return decodeURI(
        (RegExp(name + '=' + '(.+?)(&|$)').exec(window.location.search)||[,null])[1]
    );
}

var cx = getURLParameter('cx') == 'null' ? cx : getURLParameter('cx');
init(cx)
```